# Android ProgressBar set progress rounded corners

Tags: android

I have created the following progressbar style and set the corner radius to both shapes (background, and pogress). But it seems that when I animate / set progress below 90 my progressbar current progress shows rectangle shaped borders, without any radius. I would like to know if it is possible to have the corner radius all the time, even if the progress is 30 or less than 90,95. Can anyone explain why this is not working?

Also I need this to work *with the API LEVEL 8*

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="25dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="25dp" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#fff"
                    android:centerColor="#fff"
                    android:centerY="1.0"
                    android:endColor="#0d1522"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

*Update: I've added the right code that explains my problem*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After researching and doing some more tries to accomplish this I only got to the solution of using a 9patched PNG file to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

It is definately possible to have corner radius all the time. I did it by adding this line before setcontentview method of your custom progress bar.

```
customProgressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

This will make your whole view transparent. So fill the boundary inside your corners with some color.